# How to know the current security token

Tags: security, security-token

Step 1. Go to Your Name --> My Settings
Step 2. select Personal | Reset My Security Token

what shown above, creates new security token and sends email to the registered user. how can i know what is the security token value without sending email/clicking "Reset My Security Token" button

Comment: you can only check from the last sent email (unless you deleted it). within salesforce you cannot check for the current token

Answer (score 4):

From within Salesforce, you are not able to. You can either go through the emails sent to you and try to retrieve the Token or if you stored it somewhere else, retrieve it from there. Otherwise, you will have to Reset it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, whats the exact use of security token. in what scenarios can we use those?

Comment: Please google that question. If there is anything in relation to Salesforce that you do not understand related to tokens, feel free to post a new question. Thanks